# Grouping and summarizing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, count, sum, summary

I have a simple matrix with repeating values in some columns. I need to group data by names and week and sum the prices spent each day given week. here is the example:

```
 name day  week  price
 John 12   12    200
 John 14   12    70
 John 25   13    150
 John 1    14    10
 Ann  13   12    100
 Ann  15   12    100
 Ann  20   13    50
```

The desired output would be:

```
  name week sum
  John 12   270
  John 13   150
  John 14   10
  Ann  12   200
  Ann  13   50
```

Is there a nice way to do it? I used for loops, but not sure it is the best way to do it:

```
names= unique(data(:,1)); % getting unique names from data
n=size(names, 1);         % number of unique names
m=size(data(:,1),1);      % number of total rows
sum=[];                   % empty matrix for writing the results
for i = 1:n             
        temp=[];          % creating temporar matrix  
        k=1;
    for j=1:m
        if name(i)==data(j,1)     % going through all the rows and getting the rows of 
            temp(k,:)=data(j,:);  % the same name and putting in temporar matrix
            k=k+1;
        end
    end
    count=0;
    s=1;
    for l = 1:size(temp,1)-1      % going through temporar matrix of one name(e.g.John)
        if temp(l,3)==temp(l+1,3) % checking if the day of current row is equal to the
         count=count+temp(l,4);   % date of the next row (the data is sorted by name 
        else                      % and date) and then summing the prices 4th column
            sum(s, 1:3)=[names(i) temp(l,3) count];  
            count=0;              % if the days are not equal, then writing the answer
            s=s+1;                % to the output matrix sum
        end        
    end 
end
```

Comment: The combination of single-letter variable names and the lack of comments make your code  quite hard to follow. Could you expand the variable names and comment the intent of the code, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `accumarray`. It will group and aggregate values like this. You can use the third otuput argument from `unique(data(:,1))` to get the numeric indexes to pass to the `subs` argument of `accumarray`. See `doc accumarray` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to use [GRPSTATS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grpstats.html) function from Statistical Toolbox. You have to combine the `name` and `week` first to generate groups:

```
[name_week priceSum] = grpstats(price, strcat(name(:), '@', week(:)), {'gname','sum'});
```